# How to run selective thread group in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In my jmx test plan I have 10 thread groups. How to run a specific thread group in jmeter non gui mode.
[image]

In the above pic you can see I have 10 different thread groups and use case is that we might need to run only 2 thread groups to start the initial stages of tests.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way
If you want to target each thread running:

```
 - ${__P(TCRCSP1,)} - For thread Group 1 
 - ${__P(TCRCSP2,)} - For thread Group 2 
 - ${__P(TCRCSP3,)}...so on...
```

Pass the below property in each Thread group "**Number of Threads (users)**" field.

Now from the command line pass the value **Zero** for the threads which don't want to be executed and for rest the number of users like:

```
-JTCRCSP1=2 -JTCRCSP2=0 -JTCRCSP1=0....so on
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can "disable" particular Thread Group by setting it's number of threads to `0` or to a negative value or to not a number, just take the same approach as you did for threads/rampup/iteration using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
2. You can use [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter test, a minimal Taurus [YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) file which kick off a JMeter test plan with Thread Groups `TCR CSP 5` and `TCR CSP 6` [enabled and others disabled](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) will look like:

   ```
   ---
   execution:
     scenario:
       script: test.jmx
       modifications:
         disable:
           - TCR CSP 1
           - TCR CSP 2
           - TCR CSP 3
           - TCR CSP 4
           - TCR CSP 7
           - TCR CSP 8
           - TCR CSP 9
           - TCR CSP 10
         enable:
           - TCR CSP 5
           - TCR CSP 6
   ```